# Нужна ли запятая перед причастием?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая между словами "материалы" и "подходящие" в этом предложении?

*На нашем сайте вы сможете выбрать оттенки и материалы подходящие к комплектам и собственным предпочтениям.*

Answer (score 1):

*Запятая нужна.* Это обычный причастный оборот, стоящий после определяемого слова.

Только *"материалы, подходящие к собственным предпочтениям"* звучит, мягко говоря, не очень. Я бы перестроил так:

> *На нашем сайте вы по своему вкусу сможете выбрать оттенки и материалы, подходящие к комплектам.*